# Where to find Application Loader app in Mac?

Tags: macos, loader

I have downloaded `applicationloader_1.3.dmg` and installed in the destination Macintosh HD.

The messages show The installation was successfully done. But, there is the ApplicationLoader app that doesn't appear anywhere.

How to install and get the Applicationloader app in `Application->Utility` folder?

I'm using Mac OSX version 10.6.8.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

In more modern versions of Xcode, you'll find "Application Loader" under the "Xcode" menu (the first menu to the right of the Apple in the menu bar) and it'll be hiding in the "Open Developer Tools" submenu.

[image]

Comment: I have searched in my spotlight search and got the application loader app. Thanks for your spot response.

Comment: Thank you! Neither Spotlight, nor Alfred can find it. Screenshot added to show my gratitude.

Comment: None of the downloaded versions, nor the app returned from spotlight, allowed me to log in to (what it calls) 'itunes connect'. They all prompted 'invalid login'. Only the menu link from xcode, whatever it is, actually worked.

Comment: The version found by Spotlight might differ from the version you get using this approach. For me, opening Application Loader through Xcode resulted in a newer version that resolved an upload error.

Comment: Xocde 11 removed it, any way I can get it back?

Comment: Unfortunately, Application Loader has gone with Xcode 11. You may use `xcrun altool`. See `man altool`.

Comment: what is mean by xcrun altool.?

Answer (score 107):

As of **Xcode 11**, "Application Loader is no longer included with Xcode", per the [Xcode 11 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes):

> Xcode supports uploading apps from the Organizer window or from the command line with `xcodebuild` or `xcrun altool`. Application Loader is no longer included with Xcode. (29008875)

The Xcode Help page, [Upload an app to App Store Connect](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev442d7f2ca), explains how to upload from the Xcode Archives Organizer.

#### Transporter

In October 2019, Apple [announced the Transporter app](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10152019a) for macOS, now available in the [Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12).

> With Transporter you can:
>
> - Upload your .ipa or .pkg files to App Store Connect.
> - View delivery progress, including validation warnings, errors, and delivery logs, so you can quickly fix any issues.
> - See a history of past deliveries, including date and time.

This was previously a download from iTunes Connect for qualified partners ([FAQ](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/movies/faq/Transporter_Getting%20Set%20Up))

#### Notes on Using the Command Line

I've uploaded non-Xcode builds with `xcrun altool --upload-app -f path-to-build.ipa -u your-account@apple.com`. It won't show any progress, but you can see the network traffic in Activity Monitor. It finishes with `No errors uploading 'path-to-build.ipa'`.

See `xcrun altool --help` for usage. If your account has 2FA enabled, first visit https://appleid.apple.com/ and generate an app password.

Comment: Ok, but this does not work if you have a .pkg built with electron etc. I could download this https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.1.dmg and it still works, but what to do if they stop support it?

Comment: @Steffan, I added details on using `xcrun altool`. I've uploaded Expo builds downloaded from their build system, so it should work for your scenario too.

Comment: In xcode 11, you can use Transpoter application for sending the ipa to test flight.

Comment: Thx, Transporter seems to work although it takes absolute ages. FYI your link to the App Store is broken

Comment: Fixed the broken App Store link. Thanks @HenrikErlandsson!

Answer (score 30):

You can download Application Loader from Itunes Connect.

- Go to https://itunesconnect.apple.com/ , sign in, and click on **Manage Your Apps**.
- There is a **Download Application Loader** link at the bottom.

At the time of writing, this link is: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.1.dmg

Comment: v3.1: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.1.dmg

Comment: When using Xcode 11 you need to download the "Transporter" app from the Mac App Store since there is no Application Loader in Xcode 11 (only Xcode 10 and below).

Comment: both the links not working and the solution is outdated.

Answer (score 26):

I didn't find application loader anywhere, even in spotlight. You can open it through xcode.

Go to **Xcode > Open Developer Tools > Application Loader**

Comment: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Versions/A/Support

Answer (score 17):

With Xcode 11, Application Loader has been removed. The Mac App store now has an app called Transporter.

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12

Answer (score 8):

For anyone finding this now (23/09/2019) Application Loader has been removed from Xcode.

If you have built the application in Xcode you should be able to follow these instructions to upload your and distribute your project [Upload an app](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev442d7f2ca)

I am not sure what to do if you have been given a .ipa file, for example when building an Expo project, I'll update this post when i have an answer.

In the mean time more info can be found here. 
[Developer Apple - Whats new](https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/whats-new/?id=submissionsupdate7-31)

Comment: Hi, were you able to upload the ipa file?

Comment: You can download the stand alone `Application Loader` app and use that to upload .ipa files, see answer below for the link

Answer (score 5):

application loader page:
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/resources_page

application loader 3.1:
https://itunesconnect.apple.com//apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.1.dmg

Comment: I could reach the 3.1 download only by modifying the 3.0 URl manually. Documentation says 3.0. Do you have a link leading to some landing page with the 3.1 download link on it, so we know it's public release?

Comment: First link no longer has App Loader on it, second link 404s.  See other answers about Transporter.

Answer (score 4):

I have found in following way :

Go to https://itunesconnect.apple.com/ , sign in

Click "Resources and Help"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can find it by going to xcode > open developer tool > application Loader

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also upload an app using the Application Loader tool by using it from the terminal:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ denis$ altool --upload-app -f "ios-app.ipa" -u "applestore@email.com" -p "yourpassword"
```

> To use `altool` from anywhere in the terminal you could add it to your
>   PATH env variable by typing in terminal:
>
> ```
> MacBook-Pro:~ denis$ export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Support/
> MacBook-Pro:~ denis$ source ~/.bash_profile
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Now you can upload your app binary with the Transporter app.

You can download Transporter from Mac AppStore [Here](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12)

[Here](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb1c185036) apple mentioned its used for uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Application Loader now moved to tools

https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/tools

Comment: it looks like it is gone now. :(  anyway, here is the hotlink to the file
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.1.dmg

Comment: I've installed one from previous answer and couldn't sign in with it (3.1). Then I've found that I actually have it also in XCode > OpenDeveloper Tool menu and that one worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's in Applications > Xcode > Show package contents > Contents > Applications - but easier to open from Xcode!

Answer (score 0):

This error had me really scared because I make my app using Adobe AIR, so once my AIR builder (FDT) tells me it has packaged it, I really have very little I can do if it fails.

I got this error when I uploaded my ipa through the Application Loader (v3.0 [620]) that I had downloaded from the link they provide when submitting the binary. I tried uploading the ipa through Xcode > Application Loader (v3.6 [1020]) and it worked fine.

I am going to write to Apple about this once my blood pressure returns to normal.

Answer (score 0):

With Application Loader now gone from Xcode I had a look around to see how to upload an .ipa file, since I use UE4 and I don't touch Xcode at all during development. Turns out it's pretty hidden away, You need to go to Window, Organiser, Archives. The archive will only appear if you ticked the "Generate Xcode Archive Package" tickbox in Project Settings. Then you just click Distribute and it's just does it.

Comment: When you say "The archive will only appear if you ticked the "Generate Xcode Archive Package" tickbox in Project Settings".

Which project? How do you get xCode to see that Archive?

Answer (score 0):

Application Loader has been removed from XCode 11, the alternative app is Transporter. you can download it from the appstore with the following link:

https://apps.apple.com/ca/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use Transporter app instead of Application Loader.

Download Transporter App from this link: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is still looking for the Application loader, it has been removed and replaced with Apple Transporter. [Download](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12) from the mac AppStore.