# Xcode version / AppStore

Tags: xcode, version

When ready to present an app to put on the appStore; is there a minimum version of Xcode required? Or any version however old is good?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1806/_index.html),

- You should always use the [latest Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) (requires Apple ID to login)

> Note: You can build with the very latest SDK, and run your app on an earlier operating system. The Deployment Target build setting controls the lowest operating system version that your app will run on. This setting is independent of the Base SDK build setting.

## Using any other SDK is TEMPORARY

- It's important to understand that using an older SDK is a temporary workaround, not a solution. Issues preventing your app from using the latest SDK should be fixed as soon as possible. It will be much easier to fix these issues while the older build system is still supported.

## Latest & Easiest way

[Application Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094317/where-to-find-application-loader-app-in-mac)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some minimum version of the XCode, but no need to have the very latest one...

And for easy steps & guidelines to submit app in to appstore please check out the following url

[Easy Steps for App Store Submission & Certificates creation - By **iOSCodeGUIDE**](http://ioscodeguide.blogspot.in/2017/05/app-store-submission-and-certification.html)