# Stuck on authenticating when uploading to App Store

Tags: xcode, macos

I've seen a few other SO questions that are related to this; but I've been through all of the fixes with no joy.

My company had one Mac for use for the team. This worked absolutely fine. We really needed another so we have another. I exported the developer profile from the first Mac on to the second Mac. This *seemed* to work fine, we can test on local devices, etc. However, now we cannot upload on to the App Store from either Mac- they just get stuck on authentication with no error.

Things I've done:

- Tried a different connection
- Set the HTTPS proxy port to 80
- Run the application loader and XCode at the same time
- Regenerate our certificates and provisioning profiles
- Set the build settings to various combinations of certificates and profiles
- Turn it off and on again (more than once)
- Update Java
- Bump version and build numbers
- Checked the licence agreement (no updates)
- Deleted the XCode DerivedData caches

I can access the Apple developer sites just fine- developer.apple.com, the iTunes Connect stuff, all of that without trouble.

Comment: Do you have **any** expired certificates left in the keychain?

Comment: I didn't go through the keychain and remove all the certs/keys there, did not realize that would be necessary. I simply revoked them from the Apple dev center and created new ones. I could go through and remove all the certs/keys and re-download the missing ones.

Comment: I'm not sure it's **necessary**, but I can't think of anything else you might have missed. I have a faint memory of something similar where Xcode was still trying to reference old certificates.

Comment: I will delete all certs and keys from the keychain (that pertain to xcode) and re-download them.

Comment: No luck- I purged the Mac of all certs and regenerated them without any change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application Loader stuck at "Authenticating with the iTunes store" when uploading an iOS app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443425/application-loader-stuck-at-authenticating-with-the-itunes-store-when-uploadin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by erasing the private data using the builtin tool (Window -> Projects) and then deleting XCode itself and reinstalling.

Comment: Worked for me after erasing the private data, restarting XCode, and then deleting and rebuilding my app archive.  No reinstall of XCode itself was necessary.

Comment: how to erase private data? tell me clear, where to find Window->Projects ?

Answer (score 20):

Some answers on StackOverflow suggested that we *wait for some more time and be patient*, others stated that *restarting* OR *reinstalling* **Xcode** should do the trick, but none worked for me. However, updating [iTMSTransporter (Apple's command-line tool)](https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/) worked for me, and if none of the above worked for you, I believe this one should ...

Simply create a back-up for the existing installation / folders, This is important because during the (new) install your previous installations will be removed by Transporter:

```
cd ~
mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/
```

Now run the following command to update Transporter:

```
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter"
```

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: it did. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, after update to xCode 7.0.1.
In my case, cleaning project DerivedData and reboot Mac OS fixed it.

Comment: Exact same thing here. Updating Xcode wasn't even necessary. I simply restarted my computer and that did the trick xD