# Stuck on Authenticating with iTunes Store Xcode 8.3.2 (8E2002)

Tags: xcode, authentication, xcode8, itunes-store, application-loader

I was about to upload an app to iTunes connect using Xcode 8.3.2 (8E2002) and has been stuck at the stage of "Authenticating with the iTunes Store" and got an error -22421. Recently I uploaded the app and its got successfully uploaded but after updating the Xcode version got this issue.
I have validated the app, and it got succeeded.
Are there any solution or suggestion for this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application Loader stuck at "Authenticating with the iTunes store" when uploading an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443425/application-loader-stuck-at-authenticating-with-the-itunes-store-when-uploadin)

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it fixed it for me. Open Terminal and run:

- cd ~
- mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/
- "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter"

iTMSTransporter will then update itself, then you can try uploading in XCode again.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the same solution on the [Apple Dev forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/76803)

It works for me, wait 3 or 4 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Seems an inherent problem with 'Upload to App Store' item, I instead used Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader and it did the job in no time.