# Xcode 12 stuck at "Authenticating with App Store" (There is no Application Loader anymore)

Tags: ios, xcode

So I'm trying to publish my app and Xcode is now stuck here:

[image]

There is another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443425/application-loader-stuck-at-authenticating-with-the-itunes-store-when-uploadin). But this answer worked when Application Loader is still embedded within XCode. But now Application Loader has been removed from XCode but I couldn't find another solution, maybe I missed something...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was stuck for 2 days finally I found answer [here](https://www.jianshu.com/p/050afcaf8e9c). But I need to translate it. Here are the steps I did:

1. Download [Transporter app](https://apps.apple.com/id/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12) from App Store
2. Open `Terminal` and execute
   `Users/{YOUR_USER_NAME}/Applications/Transporter.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter`

*Note: I'm not sure if step 2 is actually necessary since I have downloaded Transporter app but anyway I did it and it seems to download more files.*

3. Open Xcode again and do the steps just like when you are going to publish an app, but this time choose `Export` instead of `Upload`: Archive => Distribute App => Export => follow the instructions until the end noting the location where you saved the exported file. This produces `.ipa` file.
4. Open Transporter app, then Sign In using your developer account.
5. Click "Add App" and choose the exported file.

Then follow the process until finish.

It works for me. Hope this helps someone. And please upvote the question and the answer if this has helped you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the 2021 solution, i generated a provisioning profile here https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/add and after create de provitional profile, i downloaded the file and excecuted opening this file, then this file open xcode and i can upload my file without this problem.

:D