# appname.app File under Products is red

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to get my app's binary from Xcode into the finder (clicking on the .app file under Products, then "Reveal in Finder".

My problem is that my appname.app file is highlighted in red, and Xcode 5 won't let me reveal the binary.

I believe that you need this file to submit your app to the app store.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Build your product...

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the .app file to submit to the app store. For the app store Archive the project and in the Organizer Submit the app.

See the Apple docs about how to submit an app to the app store, they are quite complete.

[Submitting Your App to the Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html)

If you need the .app file for another reason Archive and Expprt from the Organizer.

Comment: I tried to submit the app but it said "submit your app using Xcode 5.1.1 or later or Application loader 3.0 or later" What do I do?

Comment: What version of Xcode 4 do you have? For the Application Loader: In more modern versions of XCode, you'll find "Application Loader" under the "Xcode" menu (the first menu to the right of the Apple in the menu bar) and it'll be hiding in the "Open Developer Tools" submenu. From this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8094349/451475).

Comment: I have xcode 5, and i tried what you said, but it says to 'choose' What do I have to choose.

Comment: Read the document referenced in the answer, it is rather step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

```
1) Select projectname -> Click project -> Build Setting -> Search "Per-configuration Build Products Path"
2)  Remove the extra string from there.
3) Finally confirm you have to add $(BUILD_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)
4) Clean and build the project
```