# Xcode 7.1 (7B91b) You are not authorised to upload to the App Store

Tags: ios, xcode

I downloaded Xcode 7.1 from the App Store today after working from 7.1 beta downloads from developer.apple.com and have a new iOS app build to upload. So I did:

- Product > Archive
- Upload to App Store (or Validate)

But the response was:

- You are not authorised to use this service

Intriguingly, when I 'Export' the build to the Desktop and then use Application Loader 3, it uploads without error.

Is this an iTunes Connect bug? Or is there a new Xcode checkbox I've missed?

Note: I've also tried removing and re-adding my AppleID as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248496/you-are-not-authorised-to-use-this-service-itunes-app-upload-error), and restarted my Mac for good measure (which actually allowed the validation to work once), but still no luck uploading directly from Xcode > Organiser.

Comment: Note: my certificates are all set to expire in 2016, so they're not the problem.

Comment: Try to upload build with Application Loader. It gives you more info on uploading errors.

Comment: @derpoliuk It uploads fine in Application Loader, as I mentioned in the original post.

Comment: sorry, didn't read your original post carefully. Application Loader showed me verbose error (unlike Xcode) so I thought that this info might be useful for somebody.

Comment: I also am getting this error. But it fails in both Xcode and Application loader for me.

I only have one developer account, so the multiple accounts doesn't apply to me.

I am using Xcode 7.1 (not beta) and the latest version of Application Loader

in Xcode I get the error "You are not authorised to use this service"

in Application Loader I get the error "ERROR ITMS-90509: "Invalid Tool Version. The latest released version of Application Loader or Transporter is required to upload your app containing on-demand resources"
I have contacted Apple but it is now going 2 days and not heard anything

Comment: @RonMyschuk have you got the latest version of Application Loader? This answer has instructions on how to download it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17297252/5478371

Comment: I believe it is the latest, I just downloaded it a few days ago it is Version 3.1 (670). Actually my app finally uploaded this morning using Xcode (honestly I probably tried 70-80 times). I'm not sure if Apple fixed something on their end based off of my support ticket with them, but they never did get back to me anyway. I have another game to upload tomorrow, but I'm not holding my breath that it will work.

Answer (score 7):

I met the same issue today and I think it is a bug of Xcode 7.1

Finally I managed to submit my app via Application Loader. There were warnings but it did work.

Here are the basic steps:

1. Archive
2. Export
3. Xcode menu --> Xcode --> Open Developer Tool -->
   Application Loader
4. Double click "Deliver Your App" and choose the
   file exported in step #2
5. click next and follow the instructions until
   the end

Answer (score 4):

*Here's the quick solution*:

**Don't use Xcode beta versions to submit apps for release — it's beta for a reason and shouldn't be used with production code.**

### Submitting Apps

> Apps that are created using beta versions of Xcode or that are built
>   for beta versions of operating systems will not be accepted on the App
>   Store and Mac App Store. Apps that you submit should be developed
>   using the latest version of Xcode from the Mac App Store and should be
>   built for publicly available versions of iOS, OS X, and watchOS —
>   except when GM seeds are available. When a GM Seed of Xcode becomes
>   available, use it to develop your app for submission. When GM seeds of
>   iOS, OS X, or watchOS become available, build your app for these
>   versions.

↳ https://developer.apple.com/support/pre-release-software/

Comment: @I'L'l I didn't use the beta version to submit the app, I downloaded the App Store version today to submit.

Comment: @sighmon: I interpreted the part you mentioned about the beta as that being what you were actually using; you might consider omitting that from your question if it's not relevant. In light of that, maybe give the [iTunes Connect Dev Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/About.html) another look and if there's nothing that stands out of the ordinary file a bug report. It's unclear what type of libraries/frameworks you're using, although some of the newer stuff still have special requirements (eg. tvOS)

Comment: @zic10: It seems like a bug, so I would recommend reporting it. In the meantime maybe try using Application Loader as the OP mentioned.

Comment: @I'L'I can you show me where in the Apple documentation that it says that the Beta builds shouldn't be used with production code?

Comment: @RonMyschuk: Sure — read the last paragraph (https://developer.apple.com/support/pre-release-software/). Generally it's more polite to ask for the source before presuming an answer is incorrect and down voting :)

Comment: my apologies, you were correct. If this gets edited I will change my vote. No excuse, but I was very frustrated after trying unsuccessfully to upload my game for 2 days and getting the same error as the OP

Answer (score 2):

Having the same problems as all of you, just thought I'd share that I found a way to Validate successfully, you have to disable the "Include bitcode" checkbox before moving forward. As for the actual upload to App Store, no work around for that one other than use the Application Loader...

Also I've been seeing this too since XCode 6.4, but it seems once the current version has a couple of months after it's originally released it starts working again... fingers crossed that it starts working again soon, because uploading straight from Organizer is so much better. (I saw the Beta Version post, when I say after a couple of months for current version I'm not talking about Beta versions, just in case ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here.
Downloaded Xcode 7.1 from the App Store and it refuses to upload a new version.
Happily Application Loader worked ;)
Hopefully this gets fixed quickly.

One possible reason for the issue could be multiple development accounts under one name (personal and company). I've read elsewhere (apple radar) that that caused earlier problems of this kind.

Answer (score 0):

Happens here if the dev account is only admin. I had to use the central account for uploading our apps. I think this problem startet sometime with XCode 6. Didnt investigate further though since Application Loader works in cases when I dont have access to the central account.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem today.

Finally, I used the application loader to upload successfully,too.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a few solutions I have come across to solve this issue.

Most common being to remove and re-add your developer account.
This won't work on its own though, you need to also 'view details' on your account and have Xcode download your provisioning profiles again.

The other alternative is to upload your build using application loader. The disadvantage to using this solution is that should you be trying to upload using a beta build of Xcode or OSX you won't be able to change your apps .plist in the archive folder to trick iTunes connect into accepting it. In this instance all you have access to is your ipa.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the "Include bitcode" checkbox worked for me.

Comment: That didn't help me. :-(