# How to live tvOS app in app store

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, tvos9.1

I am working with a **tvOS** application and I want to live that application to apple tv-Store(tried both XCode upload and application loader ). But I get the following error

> "Unable to validate application archive of type 0x64"

Please have a look at the attached screenshot that I get in response.

> "I am not having apple tv so that I can't select that apple tv option like when we connect iPhone to mac that shows device there. I select generic tvOS device and make an archive to upload the build to the app store." –

Please help me with this. I'll be really very grateful to you.

Thanks in Advance.

Here's my attached screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use "**Application Loader**" v3.1 or v3.4 instead of Xcode this will help you to upload a TvOS app.

Source:- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20045

Application Loader will upload your application binary files to the App
Store. Application Loader offers fast uploading, stable connections, and early validation warnings.

You will get **Application Loader** by the following step:-
**Go to Xcode > Open Developer Tools > Application Loader**

If you didn't find it then this link will help to download Application Loader -[Where to find Application Loader app in Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094317/where-to-find-application-loader-app-in-mac)

Answer (score 2):

I check my whole project architecture and build setting and everything's ok. After all, I check project Asset folder I use top shelf image of different size by mistaken.Once I change that application successfully uploaded to AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to archiving a Simulator build instead of an iOS device build.  Make sure to select the correct device build in the popup menu near the upper left of Xcode before doing an Archive build that you plan on submitting to the App Store.

Comment: Hi, I am not having apple tv so that I can't select that apple tv option like when we connect iPhone to mac that shows device there. I select generic tvOS device and make an archive to upload build to app store.