# How do I create dynamic IAP on iTunesConnect?

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

I have an application which contains a list of communities, In order to access the community, the user needs to pay 10$ per month per community. There will be many communities so do I need to create product id for each community? Is it possible to create a community through the admin portal and make it available for use or submit for review to apple from the admin portal?

Is there any way or API to creating dynamic IAP?

If yes, Does it will be automatically available to the current version of the app or need to push another version?

Any other solution or suggestion will be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to create IAPs dynamically using Application Loader or Transporter. The in app purchases should become available without you needing to upload new version of your app. That said, I am really not sure what happens and what limits there are.

[Where to find Application Loader app in Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094317/where-to-find-application-loader-app-in-mac/8094349)

https://help.yudu.com/hc/en-us/articles/203869549--Bulk-Upload-In-App-Purchases-IAPs-

The other approach to solve this problem is sell credits in your app. 10$ = 10 credits. For 10 credits in the app you can buy 1 month community access. This approach is the "standard" approach for dynamic IAP problem, and the one I would recommend.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think the credit one will work for me.